# get a specific row from a list in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-controller

I am new to grails.I need to produce a report. That is why I have written a query which returns 3 rows with 4 column. Now I need to hold each row from that list in different object.
And I have no idea. Can anyone please help me on this please? Here is my attempt below :

```
public List<GroovyRowResult> createDataResultForShoreBank(List<GroovyRowResult> listPrincipalOutstandingData){
        def val = listPrincipalOutstandingData.collect { it.values()}
        println("value  >>> "+val)

}
```

listPrincipalOutstandingData as below >>>

```
/* listPrincipalOutstandingData */

       SELECT   lat.project_info_id, la.original_loan_duration, COUNT(la.id) AS loanCount, SUM(lat.principal_outstanding) AS pos
       FROM     loan_account_transaction AS lat
                INNER JOIN loan_account AS la ON (la.id = lat.`loan_account_id`)
                LEFT JOIN group_info AS gi ON (gi.id = lat.`group_info_id`)
                INNER JOIN
                (
                SELECT MAX(ilat.id) AS max_lat_id, ilat.loan_account_id
                FROM loan_account_transaction AS ilat
                WHERE ilat.`domain_status_id` = 1 AND  ilat.`office_info_id` = (SELECT id FROM office_info WHERE office_code =  'UG500013') 
                AND ilat.`project_info_id` IN ('BI0000000000000000000001','BI0000000000000000000003','BI0000000000000000000004') AND ilat.transaction_date <= '2013-04-26'
                GROUP BY ilat.loan_account_id
                ) AS tlat ON (tlat.loan_account_id = lat.`loan_account_id` AND tlat.max_lat_id = lat.id)
                WHERE  lat.`office_info_id` = (SELECT id FROM office_info WHERE office_code =   'UG500013') 
                AND lat.`project_info_id` IN ('BI0000000000000000000001','BI0000000000000000000003','BI0000000000000000000004')
                AND lat.`loan_status_id` != 2 AND lat.`loan_status_id` != 7 AND la.`domain_status_id` = 1 AND lat.`domain_status_id` = 1

                GROUP BY lat.project_info_id, la.original_loan_duration;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Your "report" is a page and you need to send your result data to this, or is a reports? What's the content of `listPrincipalOutstandingData`?

Comment: I am giving the listPrincipalOutstandingData sql. May be it can help you understanding.

Comment: Each row already *is* a separate object. They're `GroovyRowResult`s. They're contained in another object: the `List<GroovyRowResult>`. Can you be more specific about what is not working and what you've tried?

Comment: @codelark from the sql I am getting five rows which have four column each. What I need is to keep every single column value of each row in different variable. That means 5 * 4 = 20 values in 20 variable.

Comment: I have tried this >>
List<GroovyRowResult> val = listPrincipalOutstandingData.collect { it.values()}
        def mf = val.get(0)
  def mf_loan_count = mf.getAt(loanCount)
        println("All three projects principal outstanding >>> " + val)
        println("MF principal outstanding >>> "+ mf)
        println("MF loanCount 20 >>> " + mf_loan_count)